Deriving linear constraints from logical notation
I have the following two logical implications. $x_{it}$ and $y_{it}$ are binary, $N$ is an integer number. $i$ and $k$ are indexes.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{t}x_{ik}\ge N~\implies y_{it}=1$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{t}x_{ik}< N~\implies y_{it}=0
$$
How can I represent these implications as constraints?

Does this answer your question? How can one model a binary variable?

You can model the two implications as follows:
$$
N\cdot y_{it} \le \sum_{k=1}^{t}x_{ik}\le t+(N-1-t)\cdot(1-y_{it})
$$

I think you beat me by a couple of second :-)

Lets call it a tie

Thanks to both of you. I was wondering how I can integerate $t$ as it is an index?

Given upper and lower bounds on $\sum_{k=1}^t x_{ik}$, say $l$ and $u$, you can enforce your bi-implication $\sum_{k=1}^t x_{ik}\geq N\iff y_{it}=1$ using the inequalities
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^t x_{ik}\geq l+(N-l)y_{it}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^t x_{ik}\leq u - (u-(N-1))(1-y_{it})
\end{equation}
If $y_{it}=1$, then the first inequality gives $\sum_{k=1}^t x_{ik}\geq N$ and the second gives $\sum_{k=1}^t x_{ik}\leq u$. If $y_{it}=0$, on the other hand, then we have $l\leq \sum_{k=1}^t x_{ik}\leq N-1$.

Note that since $x$ is binary, $l=0$ and $u=t$.

Yes. But maybe you have stronger bounds derived from other parts of whatever model this comes from

Also I think you have typo in the second constraint, it should be $(u-(N-1))$

you are right. Typo corrected

Thanks to both of you. I was wondering how I can integerate $t$ as it is an index?

@manofthousandnames What do you mean by integrating $t$?

@Sune Well, if I understand your formulation correctly, $t$ is not a fixed value, but rather dynamic, since it changes, for example, in the case of $t=2$ to 2 and so on. Or do you mean the value of $\mid t \mid$, as the magnitude of the index?

@manofthousandnames $t$ is an integer, a fixed value. I think that maybe you are suggesting that you need the constraint for different values of $t$ (and $i$ by the way).

I see. So for instance, if $t={1,...,10}$, then I would replace $l$ with 10, correct?

@manofthousandnames $l$ should be thought of as a lower bound on the sum $\sum_{k=1}^t x_{ik}$. The other answer assumes the trivial lower bound of $l=0$ and the also obvious upper bound of $u=t$. If you substitute these two values into my answer, you get the constraints proposed in the other answer. Hence, this answer only differ, if you have additional information on $\sum_{k=1}^t x_{ik}$. In this case, you may use this answer to strengthen your formulation, but both formulations are valid.
